# UITableView cells hidden by UINavigation bar when pushing Custom Camera View to UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a custom `cameraOverlay` assigned on a `UIImagePickerDelegate` view (in this case a `UITabViewController`).

In the delegate method:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    SelectPhotoTypeViewController *destinationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelectPhotoTypeView"];

    destinationController.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] forKey:@"image"];

    [picker pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
}
```

When this runs the `SelectPhotoTypeViewController` is pushed to the `NavigationController` of the `UIImagePicker` (as it inherits from `UINavigationController`). I select a photo type in the `SelectPhotoTypeViewController` and push a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. In this view the `UITableView` first rows are hiding behind the `UINavigationBar`.

This only happens when selecting an image (i.e. taking a photo) from the `cameraOverlay` but not when selecting the image from the Gallery. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally sorted it out. I replaced the destination `UIViewController`s with `UITableViewController`s and all works well now. In other words I had `UIViewController`s with a `UITableView` which for some reason was being covered by the `UINavigationBar` when coming from the camera view. All constraints were all set properly so I have no clue why this happened. I am marking this as an answer as it is a solution, but unfortunately I don't know the reason as to why this was happening, maybe as @Juan Munhoes Junior was saying it is a status bar bug.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because the bug of status bar. Every time you make a push, you need to hide the status bar and inside the controller you show status bar again .

Something like that:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

or when pushing..

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [picker pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Do this when you push a viewcontroller for photo.

Comment: I tried this but still no luck. Seems like it is something to do with the `NavigationController` on the `UIImagePickerController` when using `cameraOverlay`. I'll try to make sure the `NavigationControllers` are set properly and post if I had any luck.